# How to read fabric(python) confirmation in jenkins job execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, fabric

We have a python deployment script for our application and we use fabric package to ask user for the confirmation to proceed further (if user fixes manually or want to ignore) with any issues during the deployment.

```
question="Failure encountered during deployment.Would you like to continue?"
if confirm(question):
   logging.info("User request to continue...")
   pass
else:
   sys.exit(1)
```

We are able to successfully read/capture the user input when we execute the python script from a linux machine.

However, when we are executing the same script from Jenkins job execute shell its not asking/waiting for the user input when there is a failure to proceed further or not and throwing the following EOF error and exiting the deployment program in middle.

> Error:
>   if confirm(question):   File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/contrib/console.py",
>   line 27, in confirm
>       response = prompt("%s [%s] " % (question, suffix)).lower()   File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line
>   211, in prompt
>       value = raw_input(prompt_str) or default EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Is there a way to pause the Jenkins job execution during the fabric confirmation question and give chance to user to enter/input something to the Jenkins job execution? if so, how to achieve/implement that process ?

Comment: What would be a reason for the user to not want to continue? A failure in the fabric operations? The functionality that you're asking for doesn't really seem like a very good idea. Why are you using both Fabric AND Jenkins to begin with?

Comment: @Harrison Health check failure after deployment(if its because of new code and cannot be fixed without doing code changes further) is one case where user not want to continue further and we will initiate a rollback process of deployment. - Pavan T

Comment: Are you unable to perform these health checks during the deployment script execution? Assuming you're using `with settings(warn_only=False)` in your Fabric script, the script should only fully complete IF everything has successfully completed. Do you have other cases that can still fail if the deployment script succeeds?

Comment: We are performing health checks and some other tasks during deployment process and using fabric asking user action (yes/no) depends on the use case of the failure.

Comment: You could use the Jenkins Pipeline plugin : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/ . I am not very familiar with it but it may help you. At some point you may have to split your Fabric script into 2 parts (pre and post-input)

Comment: @PavanTatikonda How did you solve this? I have exactly similar usecase

Comment: @user5290853 sorry, we couldn't solve this due to Jenkins doesn't have a feature to wait for user input except in the pipeline jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we couldn't solve this due to Jenkins doesn't have a feature to wait for user input except in the pipeline jobs